# Invalid date format in bash

Tags: bash, date, format

I'm having trouble with checking time since EPOCH. (and late subtract it from another one).

I get the date like this:

```
var=$(date)
echo $var
wto, 1 mar 2016, 16:00:14 CET
```

and later I'm trying to turn it into seconds since epoch:

```
date -d "$var" +"%s"
date: invalid date ‘wto, 1 mar 2016, 16:00:14 CET’
```

I'm giving this just as an example. Actually I will be **reading the date from file**, written in **default locale format** (I'm operating on couple different machines).

Comment: what locale are you using ? It's the wto and commas that are breaking it.

Comment: what is `wto` ? Thats what causing the problem here.

Comment: guys is not about the wto .. I ran the same script in my env and I got the same error `date: invalid date 'Tue Mar  1 16:30:40     2016'`

Comment: @ClaudioM That's a valid date though...

Comment: @123 yes ... and it's what I'm concerned about ..

Comment: the strange thing is that I ran the date command from command line and I got the same strange error ... `date -d "Tue Mar 1 17:01:35 2016"` output `date: invalid date 'Tue Mar 1 17:01:35 2016'`

Comment: If you are reading the date from a file, make sure the file does not have DOS line endings, in which case the date probably has a trailing carriage return.

Comment: Are you using `date` from [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)?  What version?  GNU can handle `Tue Mar 1 16:30:40 2016` but neither `1 mar 2016, 16:00:14 CET` nor `wto, 1 mar 2016, 16:00:14 CET`

Comment: I'm using date (GNU coreutils) 8.21. 

and if you read my update below, you will notice that it works with LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8, but for example doesn't work with pl_PL.UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

if you type `date -h` there is the reason why you got this error.

the `-d` option MUST be declared only with TIME and not with complete DATE format

```
-d,--date TIME  Display TIME, not 'now'
```

so

```
date -d "23:59:59"
```

then:

```
Tue Mar  1 23:59:59     2016
```

if you need get only the seconds from a date you have to execute this:

```
 date +"%S"
```

if you use the -d the output will be deplyed in msec

Comment: That is not exaclty true, as:

    date -d "2016-02-25 23:23" +"%s"

works fine...

Comment: Ok, the thing is that I have files that have this date format and I need to read this date in somehow. I guess I will have to use sed or awk - but I was hoping there's a smarter way - since the timestamp was generated by "date", I hoped it can be interpreted by "date" command...

Comment: the point is: what is the purpose of your script? what do you want from the date? please remove the downvote since I've give a solution based on what you asked...

Comment: I did not down vote you. :)

What I need is a universal script for finding the time difference between now and timestamp in a file - which would be locale independent.

Comment: According to `man date` the `--date=STRING` can be a full date: "The  `--date=STRING`  is a mostly free format human readable date string such as `"Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"`"

Comment: I think you meant **displayed** and not **deplyed**.